# no viable conversion from 'int' to 'Student'

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-keyword

(Edited version)

I am currently coding Binary Search Tree algorithm. (using xCode IDE)
I'm taking the data from txt file and insert it as binarysearchtree.
This is the sample of data from txt file.

3800 Lee, Victor; 2.8

3000 Brown, Joanne; 4.0

As you can see in student.h, there are 2 variables which are id and student. Id contains the data "3800" and student contains "Lee, Victor; 2.8". Each line of the txt consider as one root.
Now, I have to search by a unique key which is id(Ex. "3800") and print out if it is found in the tree.
I have 5 files, BinaryNode.h, BinaryTree.h, BinarySearchTree.h, Student.h, main.cpp.
All 3 of the binary header file are using template and Student.h has no template.
So, here is my int main.

```
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<Student> tree;
    getData(tree); (I didn't include getData part, but consider tree has txtfile data.)

bool found = false;
char input;
do
{
    cout << "Enter a key letter to access to a corresponding menu." << endl << endl;
    cout << "T – Print tree as an indented list" << endl;
    cout << "S – Search by a unique key (student ID)" << endl;
    cout << "B – Tree Breadth-First Traversal: Print by level" << endl;
    cout << "D – Depth-First Traversals: inorder, preorder, postorder" << endl;
    cout << "R – Find the longest branch and print it (from leaf to root)" << endl;
    cout << "H – Help" << endl;
    cout << "Q – Quit" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl;

    if(input == 'T' || input == 'S' || input == 'B' || input == 'D' || input == 'R' || input == 'H' || input == 'Q' || input == 'A')
    {
        if(input == 'T')
        {
            //print tree as indented
        }
        else if(input == 'S')
        {
            //search by student ID
            Student *result = new Student;
            int id;
           cout << "Enter the student ID to search the matching student." << endl;
            cin >> id;
            result->setId(id);
            found = tree.getEntry(*result);
        }
```

I cin the input data into result and tried to search for the data.

//My getEntry function in public function definition

```
template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getEntry(ItemType& anEntry)
{

 BinaryNode<ItemType>* returnedItem = findNode(BinaryTree<ItemType>::rootPtr, anEntry);
if (returnedItem)
{
    anEntry = returnedItem->getItem();
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

//findNode function

```
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*         
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr,
                                                       ItemType & target)
{
ItemType result = result.getId();  <------- ******error here*******
ItemType root = nodePtr->getItem().getId();

if (nodePtr == nullptr)
    return nullptr;
if (result == root)
    return root;
if (result > root)
    root = findNode(nodePtr->getRightPtr(), target);
else
    root = findNode(nodePtr->getLeftPtr(), target);
return root;
}
```

I have an error on my findNode function.

->No viable conversion from 'int' to 'Student'

//Student.h

```
class Student
{
private:
    int id;
    std::string name;

public:
    Student() { id = 0; name = ""; }
    Student(int newId, std::string newName) { id = newId; name = newName; }
    friend bool operator >= (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator == (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator < (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator > (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
/*
Student& operator = (Student& t_id)
{
    if(this != &t_id)
         id = t_id.getId();
    return *this;
}
 */
void getStudent() { std::cin >> id; }

int getId() const                        { return id; }
void setId(int t_id)                     { id = t_id; }
std::string getName() const              { return name; }
void setName(std::string t_name)         { name = t_name; }
//ItemType getGpa() const { return gpa; }
//virtual void setGpa(std::string t_gpa) { gpa = t_gpa; }
```

Do I need = operator to fix that problem?
Actually, I created the = operator but if I enable that = operator code,
the other codes with equal sign that are in other functions
encounter errors. (no viable overloaded '=')

How can I fix this errors?
Thank you for your helping.

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? There's no other informational notes in the error message? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just edited where the errors occur. That single line that I pointed to has 2 errors at the same time.

Comment: Then what is `ItemType`? What is `result`? What does `result.getId()` return? *Please* try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's really important for us to see something like to know what everything is. Otherwise all we can do is just guess, and mostly guess badly.

Comment: Joachim is right: MCVE helps us answering properly and it helps you asking better questions. But even better, quite often, it allows you to answer your question by yourself while preparing it, learning much in the process.

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do `ItemType result = result.getId();`? The `getId` function returns an int, and `ItemType` is `Student`. So how is this supposed to work?

Comment: I am so sorry about the bad question. I just edited with specific part of the code that needs.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says that you have no `operator=` defined that allows you to assign an `int` or a `string` to a `Student`. `getId()` and `getName()` returns respectively `int` and `string` and you're trying to assign their result to `ItemType` which in your case is `Student`.

You don't have a Student constructor taking an `int` or a `string` either, which makes me think you may not want an implicit conversion from `int` or `string` to `Student` (personally I wouldn't advise it).

So either:

- your code is wrong semantically and what you want to do is call another function than `getId()` and `getName()` ( I think that's the case )
- your `getId()` and `getName()` functions are wrong and should return `Student` to match the template requirements
- your template is not adapted to your object :)

One option to fix is:

```
ItemType x(a.getId(), a.getName());
```

To call the constructor taking `int` and `string`. Note that I changed the variables names because your code doesn't really make sense: you assign `result.getId()` to `result` that you just defined !!

The reason why your `operator=` is not working is that you don't take a `const` reference as parameter and therefore it can't work with `const` object on the right side of the `=`, generating new errors. However, fixing it won't make it work for `int` and `string` as long as you don't have an implicit constructor taking those.

There are many other strange things in your code, like your `getStudent()` method that is not a getter, you should name it differently and probably make it take a `istream` reference as parameter, or the usage of assignement instead of initialization list in constructors:

```
Student() : id(0), name("") {}
Student(int newId, std::string newName) : ud(newId), name(newName) {}
```

Or that both your `operator>=`, `operator>` and `operator==` actually compares with `<`.