# no viable conversion from 'int' to 'student' c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

(Edited version)

I am currently coding Binary Search Tree algorithm. (using xCode IDE)
I'm taking the data from txt file and insert it as binarysearchtree.
This is the sample of data from txt file.

3800 Lee, Victor; 2.8

3000 Brown, Joanne; 4.0

As you can see in student.h, there are 2 variables which are id and student. Id contains the data "3800" and student contains "Lee, Victor; 2.8". Each line of the txt consider as one root.
Now, I have to search by a unique key which is id(Ex. "3800") and print out if it is found in the tree.
I have 5 files, BinaryNode.h, BinaryTree.h, BinarySearchTree.h, Student.h, main.cpp.
All 3 of the binary header file are using template and Student.h has no template.
So, here is my int main.

```
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<Student> tree;
    getData(tree); (I didn't include getData part, but consider tree has txtfile data.)

bool found = false;
char input;
do
{
    cout << "Enter a key letter to access to a corresponding menu." << endl << endl;
    cout << "T – Print tree as an indented list" << endl;
    cout << "S – Search by a unique key (student ID)" << endl;
    cout << "B – Tree Breadth-First Traversal: Print by level" << endl;
    cout << "D – Depth-First Traversals: inorder, preorder, postorder" << endl;
    cout << "R – Find the longest branch and print it (from leaf to root)" << endl;
    cout << "H – Help" << endl;
    cout << "Q – Quit" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << endl;

    if(input == 'T' || input == 'S' || input == 'B' || input == 'D' || input == 'R' || input == 'H' || input == 'Q' || input == 'A')
    {
        if(input == 'T')
        {
            //print tree as indented
        }
        else if(input == 'S')
        {
            //search by student ID
            Student *result = new Student;
            int id;
           cout << "Enter the student ID to search the matching student." << endl;
            cin >> id;
            result->setId(id);
            found = tree.getEntry(*result);
        }
```

I cin the input data into result and tried to search for the data.

//My getEntry function in public function definition

```
template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getEntry(ItemType& anEntry)
{

 BinaryNode<ItemType>* returnedItem = findNode(BinaryTree<ItemType>::rootPtr, anEntry);
if (returnedItem)
{
    anEntry = returnedItem->getItem();
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

//findNode function

```
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*         
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr,
                                                       ItemType & target)
{
ItemType result = result.getId();  <------- ******error here*******
ItemType root = nodePtr->getItem().getId();

if (nodePtr == nullptr)
    return nullptr;
if (result == root)
    return root;
if (result > root)
    root = findNode(nodePtr->getRightPtr(), target);
else
    root = findNode(nodePtr->getLeftPtr(), target);
return root;
}
```

I have an error on my findNode function.

->No viable conversion from 'int' to 'Student'

//Student.h

```
class Student
{
private:
    int id;
    std::string name;

public:
    Student() { id = 0; name = ""; }
    Student(int newId, std::string newName) { id = newId; name = newName; }
    friend bool operator >= (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator == (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator < (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
friend bool operator > (const Student l, const Student& r)
{
    return std::tie(l.id, l.name) < std::tie(r.id, r.name);
}
/*
Student& operator = (Student& t_id)
{
    if(this != &t_id)
         id = t_id.getId();
    return *this;
}
 */
void getStudent() { std::cin >> id; }

int getId() const                        { return id; }
void setId(int t_id)                     { id = t_id; }
std::string getName() const              { return name; }
void setName(std::string t_name)         { name = t_name; }
//ItemType getGpa() const { return gpa; }
//virtual void setGpa(std::string t_gpa) { gpa = t_gpa; }
```

Do I need = operator to fix that problem?
Actually, I created the = operator but if I enable that = operator code,
the other codes with equal sign that are in other functions
encounter errors. (no viable overloaded '=')

How can I fix this errors?
Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Why are `result` and `root` declared as `ItemType`?  `getId` returns `int`, and `ItemType` isn't guaranteed to be an `int`.

Comment: Even if I change Itemtype to int, it gives me an another error.
" Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union"

Comment: I'm not saying that the solution is to declare them as `int`. I'm saying that you've got a mismatch there and you need to spend some more time thinking about what the type that you want to return is, and how you're going to obtain that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no viable conversion from 'int' to 'Student'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005119/no-viable-conversion-from-int-to-student)

Answer (score 1):

Just see this line.

```
ItemType root = nodePtr->getItem().getId();
```

Do you feel that something is wrong here?

Comment: Same point..
ItemType result = result.getId();  
ItemType root = nodePtr->getItem().getId();
These two lines have same error. no viable conversion from int to student

Comment: How can you convert id of type integer to an object of type ItemType?

Comment: that is what I am asking, how can I convert int to ItemType?

Comment: You can't. Whenever you need id, you will have to access it from object. Or create an integer variable temporary and assign id to it.

Comment: @BrianBkSung Think of it like this: is it possible to convert a SPECIFIC type into a GENERIC type?